# $dr$ $d\theta$ linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am trying to prove the derivatives of polar coordinates, $dr$ and $d\theta$ are linearly independent at every point of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$. I found $dr=\frac{2x \cdot dx+2y \cdot dy}{2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  $ and $d\theta=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ and I know I should find $$c_1dr+c_2d\theta=0$$ only when $c_1=c_2=0$, but I just cant to find the way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and in particular give all necessary context and definitions for people to answer your question. Good luck!

Comment: (Have you tried integrating your equation over certain closed loops in $\mathbb R^2$? Another option is for you to consider the $2$-form $d\theta\wedge dr$, and recall that $rdr\wedge d\theta = dx\wedge dy$, and that two $1$-forms $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are linearly independent if and only if the corresponding wedge is non-vanishing.)

Comment: $dr$ and $d\theta $ are not derivatives, they are linear forms